# Short link to file in template directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to make a custom login page in my template. It needs to be an independent theme, so plugins or page templates are not an option.

Is it possible to make a file called eg. `login.php` and make a permalink to `www.host.com/login/` ?
Maybe someone has another idea?

In the end it will be in an overlay box, but the page is needed if a user disables JS.

I was try this, but it's not working for me:

```
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'login_rewrites');
    function login_rewrites($wp_rewrite) {
        $newrules = array();
        $newrules['log-in/?$'] = '/wp-content/themes/candyfloss/login.php';
        $wp_rewrite->rules = $newrules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab, you want some kind of popup page executed with javascript and a fallback to another page if the link is clicked.

Without seeing your code, the short answer is yes it's possible, and it would be done something like this.

```
<script>
    function loginOverlay() {
        // ... Whatever ajavscript or jquery you want to use to pop up the javascript
        //     The link will not launch due to the 'return false' on the onClick param in the markup
        //     If javascript is turned off, it won't matter, so the browser will navigate to login.php
    }
</script>
<a href="login.php" onClick="loginOverlay(); return false;">Login</a>
```

Comment: Yes, but that will show link like: www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme/login.php :/

I'm trying with something like that, but it's not working for me:

add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'login_rewrites');
function login_rewrites($wp_rewrite) {
 $newrules = array();
 $newrules['log-in/?$'] = '/wp-content/themes/candyfloss/login.php';
 $wp_rewrite->rules = $newrules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}